# Windows 8 installed with Boot Camp does not show brightness or volume indicators when function keys are pressed

Tags: windows-8, boot-camp

I installed cleanly using Boot Camp on my MacBook Air and managed to install Boot Camp Control Panel without any problems.

My screen brightness, keyboard brightness, and volume function keys all work great, except I no longer get the indicator on the screen showing the levels of those options.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Must be a native driver problem which prevents the displaying of these options. The settings work right ?

Comment: The OP is pretty clear that the keys work to bring about the desired changes, but that the visual feedback on which key was pressed is all that's missing.

Comment: Have you tried making sure you have the latest version of Bootcamp?

Answer (score 3):

Double-check that Bootcamp.exe is running by looking in the System Tray for the black diamond icon. If it's not running, start Boot Camp in Windows by running `C:\Program Files\Boot Camp\Bootcamp.exe`.

Once Boot Camp is running, you can right-click the System Tray icon and open the Boot Camp Control Panel, then use the options in the Keyboard tab to configure your computer.

If the Fn keys stop working when you reboot, you need to add Boot Camp to Startup Items by opening `%USEPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, and dragging & dropping a shortcut to Bootcamp.exe  in there. You can create a shortcut by locating the actual Bootcamp.exe file, right-clicking, and selecting Send to Desktop (Create Shortcut).

Answer (score 0):

Bootcamp 4 does not work properly under Windows 8 (i.e. visual indicators is not visible).
Installing Bootcamp 5 ([link](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1638)) fixes this problem. (which was designed for windows 8 support)
But check the system requirements first, some models might not support it...

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue on macbook 2,1 (late 2007) running windows 10 in the following way:

- open device manager
- update intel graphic drivers with drivers provided in bootcamp
- close device manager

  - install intel graphic drivers and intel utility from bootcamp drivers

I know it's a very old post, but since I came to this several time searching for solution.. I wish this can help someone!

cheers 
BoZ